# PLSQL script not altering table?

Tags: sql, database, oracle, plsql

I am writing a simple script to alter the type of a field for our database. Here is the sql I am using

```
ALTER TABLE crew_has_new_gps MODIFY USER_ID varchar2(9 char)
```

My sql script looks like this:

```
 DECLARE
    v_odb_or_hdb  VARCHAR2(3) := 'ODB';
 BEGIN

   EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'ALTER TABLE table_name MODIFY USER_ID varchar2(9 char)';
END;
```

I have obviously removed all the unwanted code for simplicty. What could the problem be here?

Comment: and what is the problem exactly?  You problem statement is not clear.  Is there an error? Nothing happens? Something unexpected happens?

Comment: the script runs till the end but I don't see the changes in the table

Comment: What changes are you expecting exactly?  What is the initial state of the table/column before you try to run the PL/SQL script?

Comment: initially the USER_ID has 8 char and I would want to see 9 char

Comment: Can't reproduce, sorry.  Either you have a typo, have the incorrect table name, or you are not correctly observing the change.  The script should work fine.  You'll need to provide a script that we can use to reproduce your problem if you want more help.

Comment: I am also getting an output saying Cannot set autocommit...At the begining of the script I am setting autocommit to off

Comment: @TusharChutani: Are you sure you are doing this in "Oracle"? In Oracle, there is no autocommit.

Comment: Clearly you have removed so much "unwanted code" that you have removed whatever it is which is causing your problem.  So you need to publish a test case which actually *reproduces your error* .  Also you should describe what happens, including any error messages you see.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the first block you have the table name crew_has_new_gps.

In the second block you have the table name 'table_name'

Now, I don't know if that is intentional or not.  But I can tell you, using the proper table name, your script does work.

Comment: I was able to solve the problem...there was some problem with the logic of the code)  thank you and yes that was intentional